What should typing be for __add__ in a subclass of list?
This is a simplification of my code:
# my_list.py
from __future__ import annotations


class MyList(list[int]):
    def __add__(self, other: list[int]) -> MyList:
        return MyList()

mypy says:
> mypy .\my_list.py --strict
my_list.py:5: error: Signature of "__add__" incompatible with supertype "list"  [override]
my_list.py:5: note:      Superclass:
my_list.py:5: note:          @overload
my_list.py:5: note:          def __add__(self, list[int], /) -> list[int]
my_list.py:5: note:          @overload
my_list.py:5: note:          def [_S] __add__(self, list[_S], /) -> list[_S | int]
my_list.py:5: note:      Subclass:
my_list.py:5: note:          def __add__(self, list[int], /) -> MyList

If I do this, mypy no longer complains:
from typing import overload, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar("_T")

class MyList(list[int]):
    @overload
    def __add__(self, other: list[int]) -> list[int]:
        ...

    @overload
    def __add__(self, other: list[_T]) -> list[_T | int]:
        ...

    def __add__(self, other: list[_T] | list[int]) -> list[_T | int]:
        return [0]

... but then it doesn't really make sense for addition of MyLists to return lists...
Also, the problem gets much worse if we try to add a __iadd__ method... Then it either says that its signature isn't compatible with that of __add__, or is incompatible with some superclass's signature...
Signature of "__iadd__" incompatible with "__add__" of supertype "list"  [override]
Signatures of "__iadd__" and "__add__" are incompatible  [misc]

To me things should be really simple here, but they're not. Also I am aware of the Liskov Substitution Principle, and I think I've taken it into account for all of my tests.

It's Python 3.13

There's a lot of problems here: List is a generic type but instead of making a generic subclass you've only made a list of a concrete type [int]. Additionally, __add__ for lists is overloaded in the base class so that lists can be made heterogeneous like Carcigenicate said, so your subclass implementation will have to account for that. "To me things should be really simple here" why would you assume that? You're trying to add type annotations for a generic data with metaprogramming magic methods. I'm not clear why you thought this would be simple?

Dealing with this sort of thing is a big part of why people started using dynamic languages like Python in the first place.

Well... What I want my class to do is simple, describing how to use it and how not to is rather simple... So I just assumed. My bad. Anyways, thank you for your comment, I'll dive more into it tomorrow.

That's cool. My rule of thumb though is that library code (like general purpose data structures) is between 2x and 10x more difficult to type than application code. Up until this February I spent the last few years leading a team writing Typescript libraries for work, and there's a lot of culture shock for devs that primarily write JS when a normal signature for application code like function foo(a: string, b: number): number becomes function foo<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(a: T, b: K): T[K] & { tag: string } for library code.

"What should typing be"? Typing should be whatever your runtime behaviour is. mypy is correct, firstly because list is invariant, and secondly if you don't override the methods (__add__, etc.) they don't return subclass instances, they just return builtins.list (class A(list): pass; print(type(A() + A())) prints (<class 'list'>)). By returning MyList in __add__, it is strictly unsafe to upcast MyList into list - all you have to do is add a # type: ignore and never up-cast.

The Python core devs have decided that if you have a list[A], you should be able to add a list[B] to it and get a list[A | B].
If you want your custom class to "be" a list, i.e. you want to subclass it, then it must follow the same rules. You need that __add__ overload for the same reasons that you need .clear(), .reverse(), and so on. If those things don't make sense for what you're trying to build, don't subclass from list.
You might find it more helpful to subclass from abc.Sequence or abc.MutableSequence instead. They're more pared-down than list and therefore more generic and less opinionated, and you still won't have to build the whole thing from scratch.

Since you mentioned the Liskov substitution principle, here's a case that your class would violate:
def make_heterogeneous_list(input: list[int]) -> list[int | str]:
    return input + [":^)"]

Because your class subclasses list[int], you're allowed to pass in an instance of it as the input argument. So what happens when you do that, once it reaches the return input + [":^)"] part?
